# Problem with breakpoints using WinGDB+VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, gdb, embedded

I am developing embedded C for a TI MSP430 microcontroller, and have spent the last couple days migrating from TI's IDE and proprietary toolchain to a more unix-y workflow of Sublime Text + make + gcc. I'm now trying to set up debugging with WinGDB (Visual Studio with gdb backend) and I've got it mostly working. There's just this one issue with breakpoints which I suspect comes down to a backslash / forwardslash issue, but I don't know how to fix.

I can start debugging without problems, I can step through, view disassembly, etc. But when I try to set a breakpoint in the source file using F9, it shows up as disabled with the hovertext:

```
The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No source file named d:Documentsccs workspacesmsp430 scratch\013cxmain.c.

Location: main.c, line 13 ('main(void)')
```

However, I can set and clear working breakpoints with gdb commands in the WinGDB debugger shell, but no little red circles appear next to the source.

The path to main.c is D:\Documents\ccs workspaces\msp430 scratch\vcx\main.c and I discovered that the escape sequence \v corresponds to a vertical tab, or octal \013 in ascii. So I'm guessing the backslashes are screwing something up somewhere (thanks windows).

Any ideas where to look to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Your error shown is usually generated when your code is optimised by the compiler - such as `a = 2;` and never used again. But the main problem(s) could be related to your cross toolchain - on this [link](http://www.wingdb.com/docs/pages/wg_prerequisites.htm) the cross toolchain implemented in WinGDB is *CodeSourcery G++ Lite toolchain for ARM*, while your micro, MSP430 ***is not*** an ARM device. (there is an MSP432, which is ARM device).
Maybe you can look at this: www. Energia.nu, something similar to Arduino, works with several versions of MSP430.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that it is a backslash problem, the debug records generated for your files which tell the debugger which file & line resulted in which group of op codes.

You can try modifying your build process to use forward slashes everywhere, since your tool chain is gcc based it should find files named
 `D:/Documents/ccs workspaces/msp430 scratch/vcx/main.c`
but you are also likely to have problems because of spaces in your path, restructure your project so that all spaces are replaced by underscores i.e. `D:\Documents\ccs workspaces\msp430 scratch\vcx\main.c` gets moved to `D:\Documents\ccs_workspaces\msp430_scratch\vcx\main.c` etc, *spaces in paths can cause all sorts of issues.* While it is possible to escape spaces in paths it is better to just avoid them.

I would also suggest taking a look at [Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) - while not as pretty as VS it does a much better job of providing an IDE and debug environment for cross platform and embedded development.  *It is free, cross platform and open source itself.* It interfaces with GDB very well and you can customise the build tool chain that it uses for your project(s). It even comes with presets for GNU GCC for MSP340, *as well as many others,* so should be very helpful.

[image: Code::Blocks in debug mode.]